# How to traverse a transition matrix

Tags: php, if-statement, data-structures

I have a transition matrix that is 5X5.  Basically old state going to new state.  I've set up the following if statement block but was wondering if there is a more elegant solution:

```
if( ($oldStatus[$i] == "OUT" || $oldStatus[$i]=="OPEN") && $newStatus[$i] == "OUT"){
     $email[$i] = false;
     $crw  [$i] = 'OUT';
     $sort [$i] = 9;
}else if ( ($oldStatus[$i]=="OUT" || $oldStatus[$i]=="OPEN") && $newStatus[$i]=="CONFIRMED"){


}else if ( ($oldStatus[$i]=="OUT" || $oldStatus[$i]=="OPEN") && $newStatus[$i]=="WAITLIST"){


}else if ( ($oldStatus[$i]=="OUT" || $oldStatus[$i]=="OPEN") && $newStatus[$i]=="FLEXOPEN"){


}else if ( ($oldStatus[$i]=="OUT" || $oldStatus[$i]=="OPEN") && $newStatus[$i]=="FLEXCLOSE"){


}else if ($oldStatus[$i]=="CONFIRMED"  && $newStatus[$i]=="OUT"){


}else if ($oldStatus[$i]=="CONFIRMED"  && $newStatus[$i]=="CONFIRMED"){


}else if ($oldStatus[$i]=="CONFIRMED"  && $newStatus[$i]=="WAITLIST"){


}else if ($oldStatus[$i]=="CONFIRMED"  && $newStatus[$i]=="FLEXOPEN"){


}else if ($oldStatus[$i]=="CONFIRMED"  && $newStatus[$i]=="FLEXCLOSE"){


}else if ($oldStatus[$i]=="WAITLIST"   && $newStatus[$i]=="OUT"){


}else if ($oldStatus[$i]=="WAITLIST"   && $newStatus[$i]=="CONFIRMED"){


}else if ($oldStatus[$i]=="WAITLIST"   && $newStatus[$i]=="WAITLIST"){


}else if ($oldStatus[$i]=="WAITLIST"   && $newStatus[$i]=="FLEXOPEN"){


}else if ($oldStatus[$i]=="WAITLIST"   && $newStatus[$i]=="FLEXCLOSE"){


}else if ($oldStatus[$i]=="FLEXOPEN"   && $newStatus[$i]=="OUT"){


}else if ($oldStatus[$i]=="FLEXOPEN"   && $newStatus[$i]=="CONFIRMED"){


}else if ($oldStatus[$i]=="FLEXOPEN"   && $newStatus[$i]=="WAITLIST"){


}else if ($oldStatus[$i]=="FLEXOPEN"   && $newStatus[$i]=="FLEXOPEN"){


}else if ($oldStatus[$i]=="FLEXOPEN"   && $newStatus[$i]=="FLEXCLOSE"){


}else if ($oldStatus[$i]=="FLEXCLOSE"  && $newStatus[$i]=="OUT"){


}else if ($oldStatus[$i]=="FLEXCLOSE"  && $newStatus[$i]=="CONFIRMED"){


}else if ($oldStatus[$i]=="FLEXCLOSE"  && $newStatus[$i]=="WAITLIST"){


}else if ($oldStatus[$i]=="FLEXCLOSE"  && $newStatus[$i]=="FLEXOPEN"){


}else if ($oldStatus[$i]=="FLEXCLOSE"  && $newStatus[$i]=="FLEXCLOSE"){


}
```

Comment: buy the looks you could use `in_array()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can operate through switches... something like

```
switch($oldStatus[$i]) {
   case 'OPEN':
   case 'OUT':
        switch($newStatus[$i]) {
            case 'CONFIRMED':
                 //do something here
            break;
            case 'WAITLIST' {
                 //do something else here
            break;
         }
    break;
    case 'CONFIRMED':
        switch($newStatus[$i]) {
            case 'CONFIRMED':
                 //do something here
            break;
            case 'WAITLIST' {
                 //do something else here
            break;
            //do the rest of the new cases here
         }
    break;
    //do the rest of the old cases just like above here
}
```

Makes it a little prettier and easier to manage in the future if there are new options